# Getting 415 error while trying to call rest post method using spring

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, post

I am trying to implement spring rest method with post type. I am trying to retrieve JSON and convert it into java object. And returning with JSON only. Here is my code

```
package com.restService
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/user")
public class UserRestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/post/create", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> authenticateMobUser(@RequestBody User objUser) {
        String result = null;
        result = createUser(objeUser);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private String createUser(User objUser) {
        // My create user code here
        return "{\"status\":\"SUCCESS\",\"message\":\"SUCCESS\"}";
    }
}

public class User {
    String id;
    String name;
    // Getter and setters are present
}
```

Here is Spring configurations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan  base-package="com.restService" />  
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
    </bean> 
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    </bean> 
    <!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>UserManagement</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Finally here is rest client I am using to call service

```
Client client = Client.create();
String strURL = null;
String domainName = "http://localhost:8080";
strURL = domainName + "/UserManagement/user/post/create";
String input = "{\"id\":\"12345\",\"name\":\"navnath\"}";
WebResource webResource = client.resource(strURL);
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, input);
if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + response.getStatus());
}
```

When I run this code, I received "415 unsupported media type". while sending and retrieving, I am using `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` still getting this error.
Surly I am doing something wrong here but what it is, not getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you have to use MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE in your RequestMapping?
Also, try to use RestTemplate instead of client if it is possible.

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    String input = "{\"id\":\"12345\",\"name\":\"navnath\"}";
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(input, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity("/user/post/create", entity, String.class);
    if (responseEntity.getStatusCode().value() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + responseEntity.getStatusCode().getReasonPhrase());
    }
```

P.S. To solve the issue replace your AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter in spring config with .

Comment: Same exception with all these changes. And `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` which you have mentioned is already used. You can refer code which shared above. `MediaType` which used, was belongs to `javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType` package whose `APPLICATION_JSON` variable contains value `application/json`

Comment: Could you try to replace your `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` in spring config with `<mvc:annotation-driven>`? I suggest it, because `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` is [deprecated](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.html) since spring 3.2 and as I can see you are using spring 4.

Comment: P.S. I just totally reproduced your issue, and "replace your AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter in spring config with <mvc:annotation-driven>" works just fine.